# Very slow HashAggregate in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-performance, postgresql-14

I'm running into an issue where I am trying to select a sizeable chunk of data, and HashAggregate is taking 15+ seconds to calculate my groups, there are roughly 32500 records being grouped into roughly 1500.

My query is as follows:

```
EXPLAIN ANALYSE
SELECT array_agg("ProductCategory"."categoryId") as "categoryIds", array_agg("Category"."handle") as "categoryHandles",
                "ProductIndex"."shopifyId","ProductIndex"."title","ProductIndex"."description", "ProductIndex"."handle", "ProductIndex"."type",
                "ProductIndex"."vendor", "ProductIndex"."variants", "ProductIndex"."tags", "ProductIndex"."availableForSale",
                "ProductIndex"."remoteUpdatedAt", "ProductIndex"."featuredImageUrl",
                array_remove(array_agg("ProductImage"."url"), null) as "images",
                COALESCE(json_agg(json_build_object(
                            'id', "ShopifyMetafield"."id",
                            'namespace', "ShopifyMetafield"."namespace",
                            'value', "ShopifyMetafield"."value",
                            'shopifyGid', "ShopifyMetafield"."shopifyGid",
                            'resourceGid', "ShopifyMetafield"."shopifyGid",
                            'remoteCreatedAt', "ShopifyMetafield"."remoteCreatedAt",
                            'remoteUpdatedAt', "ShopifyMetafield"."remoteUpdatedAt",
                            'key', "ShopifyMetafield"."key",
                            'description', "ShopifyMetafield"."description",
                            'createdAt', "ShopifyMetafield"."createdAt",
                            'updatedAt', "ShopifyMetafield"."updatedAt"
                        )) FILTER (WHERE "ShopifyMetafield"."namespace" IS NOT NULL), '{}')::json as metafields
                FROM "ProductIndex"
                     LEFT JOIN "ShopifyMetafield"
                    ON  "ProductIndex"."id" = "ShopifyMetafield"."productIndexId"
                           AND "ShopifyMetafield".namespace IN ('product_customizer', 'product_customizer_x')
                LEFT JOIN "ProductCategory"
                ON "ProductIndex".id = "ProductCategory"."productIndexId"
                LEFT JOIN "Category"
                ON "ProductCategory"."categoryId" = "Category".id
                LEFT JOIN "ProductImage"
                    ON "ProductImage"."productId" = "ProductIndex".id
                           AND "ProductImage"."orientation" IN ('landscape', 'portrait', 'square')
                           AND "ProductImage"."quality" IN (0, 540, 720, 1080, 2048, 3840, 7680)
                WHERE "ProductIndex"."domain" = 'something.com' AND "ProductIndex"."deletedAt" is null
                GROUP BY "ProductIndex"."shopifyId", "ProductIndex"."title", "ProductIndex"."description", "ProductIndex"."handle",
                         "ProductIndex"."type", "ProductIndex"."vendor", "ProductIndex"."variants", "ProductIndex"."tags",
                         "ProductIndex"."availableForSale", "ProductIndex"."remoteUpdatedAt", "ProductIndex"."featuredImageUrl"
```

Which outputs the following:

```
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|QUERY PLAN                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|HashAggregate  (cost=35023.10..35073.95 rows=2260 width=1141) (actual time=14963.570..15011.011 rows=1555 loops=1)                                                                                                                                                                                                |
|  Group Key: "ProductIndex"."shopifyId", "ProductIndex".title, "ProductIndex".description, "ProductIndex".handle, "ProductIndex".type, "ProductIndex".vendor, "ProductIndex".variants, "ProductIndex".tags, "ProductIndex"."availableForSale", "ProductIndex"."remoteUpdatedAt", "ProductIndex"."featuredImageUrl"|
|  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 179063kB                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              |
|  ->  Gather  (cost=11209.16..34496.54 rows=13164 width=1365) (actual time=148.242..369.927 rows=121927 loops=1)                                                                                                                                                                                                  |
|        Workers Planned: 1                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        |
|        Workers Launched: 1                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       |
|        ->  Hash Left Join  (cost=10209.16..32180.14 rows=7744 width=1365) (actual time=125.882..437.170 rows=60964 loops=2)                                                                                                                                                                                      |
|              Hash Cond: ("ProductCategory"."categoryId" = "Category".id)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         |
|              ->  Parallel Hash Left Join  (cost=9648.59..31599.23 rows=7744 width=1350) (actual time=120.781..354.770 rows=60964 loops=2)                                                                                                                                                                        |
|                    Hash Cond: ("ProductIndex".id = "ProductCategory"."productIndexId")                                                                                                                                                                                                                           |
|                    ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=20.88..21927.28 rows=1597 width=1350) (actual time=0.584..161.588 rows=13714 loops=2)                                                                                                                                                                        |
|                          ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=20.46..9879.62 rows=667 width=1246) (actual time=0.537..51.504 rows=2492 loops=2)                                                                                                                                                                      |
|                                ->  Parallel Bitmap Heap Scan on "ProductIndex"  (cost=20.04..3673.35 rows=667 width=1029) (actual time=0.457..7.834 rows=778 loops=2)                                                                                                                                            |
|                                      Recheck Cond: (("deletedAt" IS NULL) AND ((domain)::text = 'something.com'::text))                                                                                                                                                                          |
|                                      Heap Blocks: exact=4                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        |
|                                      ->  Bitmap Index Scan on productindex_domain_deletedat_index2  (cost=0.00..19.76 rows=1134 width=0) (actual time=0.272..0.273 rows=1555 loops=1)                                                                                                                            |
|                                            Index Cond: (("deletedAt" IS NULL) AND ((domain)::text = 'something.com'::text))                                                                                                                                                                      |
|                                ->  Index Scan using shopifymetafield_productindexid_namespace_index on "ShopifyMetafield"  (cost=0.42..9.29 rows=1 width=233) (actual time=0.020..0.042 rows=3 loops=1555)                                                                                                       |
|                                      Index Cond: (("productIndexId" = "ProductIndex".id) AND ((namespace)::text = ANY ('{product_customizer,product_customizer_x}'::text[])))                                                                                                                                    |
|                          ->  Index Scan using productimage_productid_orientation_quality_index on "ProductImage"  (cost=0.42..18.01 rows=5 width=120) (actual time=0.014..0.037 rows=6 loops=4983)                                                                                                               |
|                                Index Cond: ("productId" = "ProductIndex".id)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     |
|                                Filter: (((orientation)::text = ANY ('{landscape,portrait,square}'::text[])) AND (quality = ANY ('{0,540,720,1080,2048,3840,7680}'::integer[])))                                                                                                                                  |
|                                Rows Removed by Filter: 0                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         |
|                    ->  Parallel Hash  (cost=6883.98..6883.98 rows=219498 width=32) (actual time=115.967..115.968 rows=263640 loops=2)                                                                                                                                                                            |
|                          Buckets: 1048576  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 41248kB                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     |
|                          ->  Parallel Seq Scan on "ProductCategory"  (cost=0.00..6883.98 rows=219498 width=32) (actual time=0.015..27.769 rows=263640 loops=2)                                                                                                                                                   |
|              ->  Hash  (cost=446.92..446.92 rows=9092 width=31) (actual time=5.041..5.042 rows=9092 loops=2)                                                                                                                                                                                                     |
|                    Buckets: 16384  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 691kB                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               |
|                    ->  Seq Scan on "Category"  (cost=0.00..446.92 rows=9092 width=31) (actual time=0.022..2.456 rows=9092 loops=2)                                                                                                                                                                               |
|Planning Time: 2.592 ms                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           |
|Execution Time: 15020.786 ms                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I have now turned to https://explain.dalibo.com/ to look for issues in my plan, and it's saying that although the duration is in the aggregate, the cost comes from 2 of the left joins, so now I'm left confused on where to look to optimise this query.

I will include images of dalibo below, but you can also see the plan here: [the plan](https://explain.dalibo.com/plan/2cbea71bc1e0f1df#plan)

High cost left joins:
[image: High cost left joins]

High duration aggregate:
[image: High duration aggregate]

Any thoughts would be welcome.

Comment: If you run that query but with just one aggregate expression at a time, is there one particular aggregate expression which takes a disproportionate amount of time?

Comment: The time is measured, while the costs are just estimates. So the cost estimates explain why it chose a particular plan., but the measured time tells you where the time went.

Comment: The final step has a large row width (1.1KB) and is reading ~11GB of data from cache. Looks like there are numerous images associated with each row, so it will take a while to copy those around. You might drop the images out if you don't need them for the query.

Comment: `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` might show some more information.

Comment: @jjanes no. But removing the productImage join speeds it up massively, but that’s because the images are most of the rows.

Comment: @dwhitemv all the content is required.

Comment: May be a case to apply "Join to the aggregate, don't aggregate the join." Collect the `array_agg()` values with their own subquery/CTEs then join on `productIndexId`. That would get rid of the big `GROUP BY` crunch at the end.